# Read and modify POST fields "on-the-fly" using Fiddler

Tags: http, post, proxy, fiddler

I need to use Fiddler to modify the POST fields sent by a browser. I know I can do that using the Fiddler UI but I want to create a script to do it automatically.

I need to insert the code inside the OnBeforeRequest method and I know I can use regular expressions to parse the POST fields but maybe there is something already available to do it like some sort of object POST with all the current fields, e.g: POST["field1"], POST["field2"], etc.

So...is it possible or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler itself does not contain a script-accessible POST body parser, which means you'd either need to import one, write one, or use string processing to accomplish this task.